What's the difference between the addi and li instructions in RISC-V? Which one is more efficient?
I have a simple question regarding the difference between the instruction addi and li.
I'm have a code with this instruction li a2, 20, but this one was recommended instead addi a2, x0, 20.
I would love if anyone got into the intricate details of time difference or number of cycles and which one is better. :)

There is no li instruction in the hardware.  The li is a "pseudo instruction" that can be simulated with addi or ori, or some combination of several instructions, depending on the size of the immediate; the assembler does the substitution.  See here for some more info.

There's no good reason to use a more complex instruction (e.g. three operand addi with x0 as one operand) when there are simpler more readable ways to express your intent.  So, I would generally disagree with that recommendation  — except when your coding instructions specifically say to avoid pseudo instructions to learn about them and their replacements with actual hardware instructions.
